# Where do I set the Caps Lock key behaviour?

Tags: xorg

I have notice that since a few days my cap lock stays on if I press on caps lock. I can't desactivate it. I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04LTS on my old Emachines computer. So I would like to know where is the command to get back the default settings when I press the caps lock.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### For 16.04 LTS and newer:

Unfortunately disabling <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> can no longer be done from the keyboard system settings as depicted below. We will have to install and run **dconf-editor** to add `'caps:none'` to *or.gnome.desktop.input-
sources.xkb-options*.

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

[image]

This can also be done from a terminal with the following command:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['caps:none']"
```

---

#### For 14.04 and older:

Click on the Ubuntu button and search for *"Keyboard Layout"* and select *"Options..."* or from *System Settings...* open the *"Keyboard Layout"* and select *"Options..."*.

Look for the **Caps Lock key behaviour** entry and unfold the list of options to give you this:

[image]

Comment: for even newer ones, adding 'ctrl:nocaps' in the array of xkb-options in dconf-editor did the trick for me (ubuntu Wily 15.10).

Comment: Is there any way to get to this menu in 16.04?

Comment: @NathanHinchey: thank your for that hint... sadly this option was deprecated 16.04. See edit for the dconf way.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Xubuntu 18.04.